# Classic ASP Script to Create XML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I am in need of using classic ASP to create an XML file from a SQL2005 express database. I am receving a 500 error. I believe my problem is the connection string, I was wondering if I could get a fresh set of eyes on this to possibly provide me a new avenue. Here is the code:

```
<%
Dim objConn, strConnect, strSQL, rs, tb, objFSO, xmlFile, objWrite
xmlFile = Server.MapPath("inventory.xml")
tb = chr(9)
set objFSO  = Server.CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
objConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=mybox.com;Initial      Catalog=myDB;UserId=myID;Password=myPW;"

If Not objFSO.FileExists( xmlFile ) Then objFSO.CreateTextFile( xmlFile )
set objWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile( xmlFile, 2 )


objWrite.WriteLine("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?>")
objWrite.WriteLine("<data>")

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1"
Set rs = objConn.Execute(StrSQL)


Do While not rs.EOF
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & "<marker>")
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<name>" & rs("name") & "</name>")
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<address>" & replace(rs("address"),"&","&amp;") & "</address>")
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<city>" & rs("city") & "</city>")
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<state>" & rs("size") & "</state>")
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<zipcode>" & rs("zipcode") & "</zipcode>")
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<lat>" & rs("lat") & "</lat>")
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<lng>" & rs("lng") & "</lng>")
objWrite.WriteLine(tb & "</marker>")
rs.MoveNext
Loop


objWrite.WriteLine("</data>")
objWrite.Close()
%>
```

I appreciate any fresh perspective anyone can share.
Thanks,
--Matt

Comment: Not related to your 500 error, and so this is only a comment, but you need to sanitize the data fields in each record to ensure well-formed xml in your output.  That means at minimum looking for stray ampersands (&), less -thans (<) and a few other stray characters that may be in your data, and maybe using cdata sections if your character data is too varied to handle it simply.

Comment: Also, you should be able to find the exact error message.  Error 500 is only the http error created to wrap around the real error that we want to know about.

Comment: Another nitpick not related to your error is that it's not a good idea to check for `.FileExists()`.  Instead, wrap your call to `CreateTextFile()` in code that checks for and handles the error appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that stands out most to me is your connection string.  I'm not sure how it handles the extra spaces in `"Initial    Catalog"`, but I can say that `mybox.com` is almost certainly the wrong value for the data source.  You should use an internal name there, and not expose your database to the public internet.

Also, it's been a long time since I've used classic asp, but IIRC you need to call `.MoveNext()` before accessing any records — at the top of the loop rather than the bottom.

Finally, don't forget to close your connection, and use good error handling there to make sure it will reach the code that closes both the connection and the file, even if an error occurs earlier in the code. Otherwise you'll end up locking the file or database on yourself.